# There is a course in which they teach you to use WinAFL?

Tags: windows, exploit, patch-reversing, api-reversing, api-hacking

I would like to know if there is a course that begins in a basic way, such as how to use winAFL to find bugs in app desktop.

Comment: Asking for a reference to a course is likely off topic.

Comment: Where can i get the knowlege about my answer's question?